# Angular : Dynamic routing with different modules version

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm very new to Angular, and I'm facing an issue that no other topic here seems to cover.

In few words, my application starts with a dashboard, containing multiple tiles, with each one redirecting to a specific feature. Nothing fancy here.
The twist here is that each feature can be used in different version (according to the logged in user for instance).

So let's say my user A has rights to access the Stock feature in v1.0, the route would be : `mydomain.com/stock/1.0/`, using the component in `app/modules/stock/1.0/main.component`.

And if my user B has rights for v1.1, the route is : `mydomain.com/stock/1.1/`, using the component in `app/modules/stock/1.1/main.component`.

So my problem is, I could modifiy the `stock-routing.module.ts` and create a route object in the const routes for each version. But that would imply to modify it each time a new version comes in.

So I wondered if there was a way to get the version in the url and give to the 'loadChildren' property (for lazy loading) the physical path with this version variable in it.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't think that this is possible. When building your app the lazy loaded packages are created based on your routing and when the routes are based on runtime variable values (obviously not availiable during build) this can not work. I have never tried anything in that direction, but that's what I think about this.

Comment: Here comes the idea of roles and there specified rights, you can handle this thing by getting versions rights along with login info whenever a user logged in and set them in `localStorage` or some shared service which you can access globally, and then set your routes accordingly.

Comment: @Fussel Well that makes sense, I'll have a deeper look et that. Thanks !

Comment: @WasifAle Interesting point of view. I can check that. Thanks !